# RRULE 20 days after every 15th in a month,in icalendar (RFC 5545）？

Tags: icalendar

I'm searching a way to express a situation like this in icalendar: an event happens every month, x days after a given date.

e.g.: 20 days after 15th day in every month. so, it might be 3rd, 4th, 5th,6th( like February )
if bymonthday can be set to 35, it's ok.

But in outlook this won't work.
How to solve this question?

Comment: Actually，I wanna present a time like: x DAYS after **BYMONTHDAY**.

Answer (score 0):

You could perhaps try adding ";BYSETPOS=20" to the rule. The specification shows an example of BYSETPOS when using it with BYDAY, but it is not clear to me how it is handled when using BYMONTHDAY. I don't see another option looking at the spec.

http://icalendar.org/iCalendar-RFC-5545/3-3-10-recurrence-rule.html

http://icalendar.org/iCalendar-RFC-5545/3-8-5-3-recurrence-rule.html

Comment: thanks, zcontent. I tried this way, but it won't work. in the article, it says BYSETPOS means the Nth occurrence conjuntion with BYXXX. if i conjunction BYSETPOS with BYMONTHDAY, it means the 20th occurrence, the 15th day in a month, which means 20 months after the first day.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, what you want is not possible with a RRULE.

What you want is RRULE:FREQ=MONTHLY;BYMONTHDAY=35.  Unfortunately, it's invalid - BYMONTHDAY can't exceed 31.

BYSETPOS won't work either.  In RFC 5545, page 43 under BYSETPOS is the following:
"BYSETPOS operates on a set of recurrence instances in one interval of the recurrence rule."
That means you can't get a value beyond the interval.  If you use Monthly you are restricted to the one month.

If you want to experiment with some RRULEs try my recurrence rule (RRULE parser) at
http://balsoftware.net/index.php/open-source/rrule-parser/